# Can someone clarify the difference between the two?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
info:  .word   seven
       .word   three
       .word   ten
       .word   one
       .word   five
       .word   two
       .word   nine
       .word   eight
       .word   four
       .word   six


info: .word 7, 3, 10, 1, 5, 2, 9, 8, 4, 6
```

I understand the second one, but unable to understand the first declaration method.

Comment: the first is a "table" of pointers to other labels. useg e.g. if you want to store the addresses of stings (of different lengths), to be able to work on them like on an array

Comment: We don't know what the symbol names in the first one mean. If they are defined to be the respective number, then both are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is array of pointers and the second is the array itself.